# How should I add user info in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a Laravel app nearly complete except for some user info which I need to store.  This info will be added after sign up and affectively powers a directory of users - it's for information purposes only.

Some example info I wish to store:

- Address (separate lines)
- Image (uploaded, not gravatar or similar)
- Company name
- etc.

It hits me there are 2 obvious places this info could go.  Firstly, in the `users` table.  I am using Laravel 5's built-in authentication.  My idea would be to add columns to this table manually (using a migration) and then populate/extract data using Eloquent and the `Auth::user()` method.

The second is to do what a lot of other systems do and create a `users_meta` table that contains all of the attached information.  The beauty of this is that it keeps non-Laravel-specific data outside of the Laravel-specific tables.  I'd then need to create a model for this table and link it using the `hasOne` method from the Users model.  I can then get the information by using `Auth::user()->metainfo()` or similar.

There appears to be no clear answer on which direction I should head with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

They are properties of users, so I'd add it to the Users table.

Answer (score 0):

If you might add more data, I'd create a `user_data` table with columns like `user_id`, `data_type`, `data`, `updated_at`, etc., and relate it to `users`. Otherwise just keep it simple and add it directly to `users`.